# Can't call a $function()

Tags: jquery

I have carousel image plug-in, like in iTunes.
I don't know why this is not working.

I think my problem may be the way I call the below function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        alert();

        var $coverflowContainer = $('#coverflow'),
            $coverflowItems = $coverflowContainer.children(),
            $imageCaption = $('#imageCaption'),
            $slider = $('#slider-vertical'),
            $playlistItems = $('#playlist li');

        $slider.slider({
            orientation: 'vertical',
            min: 0,
            max: $coverflowItems.length - 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $coverflowContainer.coverflow('select', ui.value);
            }
        });

        $coverflowContainer.coverflow({
            select: function(ev, ui) {
                $imageCaption.text(
                ui.active.data('artist') + ' - ' + ui.active.data('album'));

                $slider.slider('value', ui.index);

                $playlistItems.removeClass('ui-selected');
                $playlistItems.eq(ui.index).addClass('ui-selected');
            }
        });

        $playlistItems.on('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            $coverflowContainer.coverflow('select', $playlistItems.index($(this)));
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the link:

```
<a href="#">Kings Of Leon - Come Around Sunshine</a>
```

Why is the link not triggering the `alert()` ?

Comment: Why prefix variables with the dollar sign? And nothing will call `alert` but the document.ready event.

Comment: Have you added jquery library? Check your error console to know any script errors

Comment: @GrantThomas To denote jQuery instance variables. So you can easily distinguish them from normal strings, numbers, array.

Comment: @dfsq Can't say I know of the standard of usefulness, certainly never needed such.

Comment: @GrantThomas: It is a very useful and widely used form of Hungarian notation preventing a lot of debugging issues, specially when working on large scale application in which several dozens of programmers work simultaneously together. When programming with jQuery this will indicate a variable is intended to contain a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: @GrantThomas In fact it's very usefull and convinient. So you always know that you can use jQuery methods. When I see `$playlistItems` I don't need to check the type of the variable I already know I can use `.on`, or `.each`, etc.

Comment: I third the usefulness of `$` prefix on jQuery objects. Very widely used convention, and very useful too.

Comment: @dfsq Surely that's not the purpose of it? Knowing your variables, and the types etc. is a responsibility of the developer, yes these things can be convenient but that seems like a hack to me. I won't negate the usefulness (not having the direct experience) but I hazard to say no feature in any language should be for _that_.

Comment: @GrantThomas Just like with any convention you are not obligated to follow it. This is the same as putting an underscore in front of private methods. But still you have to remember it's private.

Comment: @dfsq I understand, I guess my uncomfortabless comes from using what I would consider a 'special' character 'frivolously'. If it actually _did_ something to the variables, like a side-effect of demarcation then I could maybe value its use but as a naming convention, the character seems a weird one to me. Using special characters in variables might be perfectly normal to some (say, PHPers where it's a construct of the language).

Comment: @FrançoisWahl My last comment applies to your response, too. Thanks your painting a picture of your scenario.

Comment: @GrantThomas Why is it "a weird one"? jQuery uses `$` as a shorthand for `jQuery` so it makes perfect sense (to me) to choose `$` as the prefix that denotes a variable contains a jQuery object. It's also really no different to giving your variables meaningful names rather than calling them `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist But that's now how it's being used, it's being used as a literal character in a variable _name_, right? I just can't think of many languages (personally) where this would even be legal (in precise terms of its usage here, literally), and I tend to stay away from conventions that can't be translated to transferable practices where it's perfectly normal that they can be and often are.

Comment: @GrantThomas Yes, it's a character in a variable name. But for jQuery developers the presence of that character at the start of the variable name has a specific meaning: "this variable will contain a jQuery object". I'm not really sure why you're adverse to conventions that can't be applied universally, seems unnecessarily restrictive to have a "I can't apply this to everything so it has no use for me" mentality.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And that's fine, what are you getting at? How many more ways can one say, or would you like to me explicitly say, to make sure people know they're correct and keep their egos: _'That's fine, and they're welcome to it, however weird I think it is_.' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the code you've set up is in the `$(document).ready(function(){})` event handler (shortened in your case to `$(function(){})`) instead of any click handler.

Change your code to react to any link:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){});
```

or more likely, to a specific class of links:

```
$('a.songlink').on('click',function(){});

<a href="#" class="songlink">Kings Of Leon - Come Around Sunshine</a>
```